# Get the current selection on PowerPoint Add-In

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I'm developing a Add-in for PowerPoint that inserts images in the document.
I'm currently able to insert the image, but what I'm not able to do is to replace a current selected image.

So, for example, imagine that:

1. The user added an image available on the Add-in, inside an empty slide
2. He then selected this image and wants to replace it with another one also available on the Add-in.
3. He clicks/selects the slide image, and then clicks on the image inside the Add-in that he wants to replace.

The thing is that I'm not able to get his selection with the Office API.
Can someone help me?

My current code looks like this:

```
  const insertFile = (binaryStr: string) => {
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(
      binaryStr,
      {
        coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
      },
      (result) => {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
          console.error(result.error.message);
        }
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, it just doesn't work. I select the image that I want to replace and then I run the same script above and I end up with two images on the slide instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [getSelectedDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getselecteddataasync-member(1)) method which reads the data contained in the current selection in the document.

Comment: I did try to do it. I've added a `getSelectedDataAsync` to every `CoercionType` that it provides, then I selected the image that I wanted to replace and execute the script above with the `getSelectedDataAsync` on it to see if it worked but in the end I just got this: `'Unsupported Enumeration', message: "The enumeration isn't supported in the current host application.", code: 5007`

Comment: It's not Excel, it's PowerPoint. But I'm running it on version 2201 (Build 14827)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to "flag" your images ina  certain way so that you can easily pull them out to manage later.  I am using tags.

After inserting an image with `.setSelectedDataAsync(...)` the new image is supposed to be the selected shape. So if you get the selected shape you can add a tag to it in order to manage it later.

```
const selectedShapes = context.presentation.getSelectedShapes();
  selectedShapes.load('items');
  context.sync().then(function () {
    if (selectedShapes.items.length > 0) {
      const shape = selectedShapes.items[0];
      shape.tags.add("tagName", "mytag");
    }
  })
```

Then later you can search shapes based on the tag you added:

```
await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const slides = context.presentation.slides.load("items");
    await context.sync();

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.items.length; i++) {
      const currentSlide = slides.items[i];
      const shapes = currentSlide.shapes.load("items");
      await context.sync();

      for (let shapeIndex = 0; shapeIndex < shapes.items.length; shapeIndex++) {
        const currentShape = shapes.items[shapeIndex];
        const tags = currentShape.tags.load("key, value");
        await context.sync();

        for (let tagIndex = 0; tagIndex < tags.items.length; tagIndex++) {
          const currentTag = tags.items[tagIndex];
          
          if (currentTag.key === "myTag") {
            ... do something here
          }
        }
      }
    }
```